# Force words hyphenation inside label

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have s string `one, two, three` and a label. How can I force each word to be in separate line inside label using auto-lauout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using autolayout with the following constraints on `uilabel`.

1. Center horizontal and vertical in container.
2. Give a width constraint in such a way that it break to next line.
3. Don't give height constraint.
4. Set lines number of `uilabel` to 0

Have a look at this GIF.

[image]

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thats a great tutorial! Thanks a lot!